# Gradle tests multithreading on K8S container doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, kubernetes

I am trying to run Gradle tests simultaniously on k8s pod which has 8 cores and 16RAM.

This line is working when I run gradle-tests locally, but on the pod I always get 1 free processor, although I see 8 processors with 5% usage. (using `htop`):

`maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1`

I am running on EKS 1.20 and Gradle 6.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out the Gradle JVM is only detecting 1 CPU when running in a container, as a workaround you can set `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4` and `availableProcessors()` will return 4.